# No action clicking on Bootstrap popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, onclick, popupwindow

I need to implement a pop up window on clicking one link.
My HTML Code snippet:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="/stylesheets/script.js"></script>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
     <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

     <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/bootstrap-theme.css' />
     <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/bootstrap-theme.min.css' />
     <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/bootstrap.css' />
     <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css' />
</head>

  <body style="overflow-x:hidden">
<!--Header--> 
 <div id = "header">
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/kanbannew">Welcome</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-whatever="Add Card">Add Card</a></li>
      <li><a href="KanbanprojectStatus">Project Status</a></li>
      <li><a href="index">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

```
 <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
 <script>
  $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var li = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
 var recipient = li.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
 var modal = $(this)
 modal.find('.modal-title').text(recipient)
  })
  </script>
</body>
```

Clicking on 'Add Card' button of the header, I want to show a pop up where user can input some title and description and submit the same. But this sample modal is not even opening. Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: i dont see your bootstrap css file

Comment: Added, still no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `data-target="#myModal"` is referring to a `<div>` that should have an `id='myModal'`

Hence change this line

```
<div class="modal fade">
```

to

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
```

and it should work.

**Note:** You are missing the *bootstrap.css* file.

**Update:**

you should load `jQuery` first. Remove your `scripts` and `links` and load it in this manner:

```
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css' />
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/bootstrap-theme.css' />
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/bootstrap-theme.min.css' />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">   
 </script>
 <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js">  
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/stylesheets/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried that and still its's not working Updated the Question with the id="myModel". Thanks.

Comment: @Katie. I tested your code http://www.bootply.com/new and it works fine. Any errors in console?

Comment: Yeah, it works for me too in bootply.com. I am unable to identify why its not working on my local. I don't see any error in the console. Could you plz tell me if the css, js and jQuery I am using is enough to make the modal work? or Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: @Katie. I guess I see the problem now. You are loading `bootstrap.min.js` before `jquery`. And also your are loading `jQuery` too many times. Only one is enough. I will update my answer.

Comment: Cool, Thanks for the catch. I have one more problem now, the popup modal doesn't stay after opening. I just blinks for a sec and go away. Any idea why?

Comment: I figured it out, it was because I had both bootstarp.js and bootstrap.min.js. I removed bootstrap.js and its working fine now. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2):

Follow this pattern. Your style sheet should always be above your JS script.It is a good practice and a right way to place style sheet in the head section. Your Jquery core file should always be the first JS file to load as the Page is called which binds all the rest of your JS files. Try these files in similar pattern and remove all the other head files for now. click here for example http://www.bootply.com/Zdq6rSSvUs

```
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css' />

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Comment: I tried as mentioned by Sourabh and it worked. Thanks for your comment.